# Calculating P- value

Tags: r, self-study, anova, p-value, inference

In ANOVA table , I got

$F$-statistic $=330.285$

degrees of freedom (df) due to regression $= 6$

Error degrees of freedom $= 9$

But i don't know how to calculate $p-$value ?

I have tried in `R` software as

> pf ( 330.285, 6, 9, lower.tail = F )
>
> [1] 1

But it doesn't match with the result which is actually .000

Where am i doing mistake ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the command you stated and got

```
> pf( 330.285, 2, 26, lower.tail = F )
[1] 3.294207e-19
```

which is very close to the value you are expecting.

Comment: Please, see the edit . I've wrote wrong df in the first post.

Comment: But also i am getting 1 in `pf( 330.285, 2, 26, lower.tail = F )` . Why !!!

Comment: It is still working: `pf ( 330.285, 6, 9, lower.tail = F )
[1] 4.984053e-10`

Comment: Try reinstalling your R and stats package

Comment: Oh , it is working now when i have defined `lower.tail=FALSE` instead of `lower.tail=F` . STRANGE !!!

Comment: ABC -- I bet you have defined `F` as a variable which it will then use. What happens when you do `str(F)`? ... to be safe, always type `FALSE` in full.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that the problem is that you have `F` defined as a variable. Try

```
pf(330.285, 6, 9, lower.tail = FALSE)
```

Let this be a lesson to you: use `TRUE` and `FALSE`, not `T` and `F`!

Comment: Yes , you are absolutely right. I've defined F=330.285 and also wrote `lower.tail=F`  .